# 3rd-party libraries copied to /lib directory in Ant/Ivy projects

Tags: ant, dependency-management, ivy

I recently saw a project with quite a few sub-projects, each of them with a `build.xml` and an `ivy.xml`.

When building these sub-projects apparently all 3<sup>rd</sup>-party libraries declared as dependencies are copied to a `/lib` directory in *each* of the sub-projects. Coming from Maven this looks really strange.

Is this a limitation of Ant/Ivy not being able to build a classpath from the local `~/.ivy2/cache`?

Or is it a lack of Ant/Ivy knowledge at those who created the respective `xml`s?

Or is there a good reason to do this exactly like this with Ant/Ivy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to comment without seeing the ANT build files, but your description would suggest that the ivy [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task is not being used.

Hopefully the following answers will help explain how ivy configurations (similar to Maven scopes) can be used to manage classpaths exactly like Maven:

- [Ivy, what is the master configuration and why is it not pulling jvyaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417304/ivy-what-is-the-master-configuration-and-why-is-it-not-pulling-jvyaml/11420292#11420292)
- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)