# How to exclude an artifact in Ivy

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ivy

I have a project which has dependency on a module reportXXX and this reportXXX has dependency on jasper report modules. So jasperreports-javaflow.jar is imported which I don't want.

How to exclude this jar from my project? I try the following but it doesn't work.

```
<dependency org="OrgXXX" name="reportXXX" rev="1.01.01.001" conf="compile,run">
    <exclude org="jaspersoft" name="jasperreports-javaflow" type="jar" />
</dependency>
```

Comment: By "doesn't work", I assume you mean "the dependency is not excluded". Can you check that the `org` and `name` are correct in the `<exclude>` (i.e. it is really the info of the dependency to exclude)?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417304/ivy-what-is-the-master-configuration-and-why-is-it-not-pulling-jvyaml/11420292#11420292

Answer (score 1):

Try **module** instead of **name**.

`<dependency org="OrgXXX" name="reportXXX" rev="1.01.01.001" conf="compile,run">
    <exclude org="jaspersoft" module="jasperreports-javaflow" type="jar" />
  </dependency>`