# Ivy conf struggle

Tags: java, apache, configuration, ivy

I am currently struggling with apache ivy's conf settings. Maybe i'll explain
what i want to achieve first:

1. I want two configurations: compile, runtime
2. I want for each configuration that ivy resolves, all jars including the transitive dependencies

Here's something i tried:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" visibility="public"/>
    <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" extends="compile"/>
</configurations>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.apache.ivy" name="ivy" rev="2.4.0" conf="runtime->runtime, compile->compile"/>
</dependencies>
```

But it cannot even be parsed:
The ivy file '...\ivy.xml' could not be parsed:

Could please someone tell me how to declare the conf settings properly, so that i can resolve using either compile or runtime and get all jars including the transitive dependencies(in the example case only the jars of ivy).

**Update**

Ok, thanks for the links. This makes it a bit clearer, but i'm still stuck.

I changed the dependency declaration so that it resolves the ivy jars in scope 'default':
(I left out the "compile->default" declaration, as it seems there's a bug in the
parsing of ivy eclipse plugin)

```
<dependency org="org.apache.ivy" name="ivy" rev="2.4.0" conf="runtime->default"/>
```

and retrieved the jars (using the ivy eclipse plugin) with the settings 
`confs='*' and types='*'`.

All i got was a single ivy-2.4.0.jar. I expected all runtime dependencies. I can't exactly tell which they are, as i don't understand the declarations in ivy's xml file like(the whole xml file is appended later):

```
<dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant" rev="1.7.1" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
```

Here's how i understand the conf="runtime->default" declaration:

- The ivy dependency is assigned to (local) conf 'runtime'
- The ivy dependency is assigned to remote conf 'default'
- Whenever i resolve (or retrieve) the dependency for conf 'runtime' i 
  get all of the remote dependencies including the transitive dependencies 
  for conf 'default', as the 'default' conf is declared as

  "The remote module's artifact and all it's runtime transitive dependencies" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417304/ivy-what-is-the-master-configuration-and-why-is-it-not-pulling-jvyaml/11420292#11420292)

Here's my ivy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="My Name" module="jaculon.ivy" status="integration">
    </info>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths."/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive."/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath." extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases." extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."/>
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Need ivy to resolve the jars. -->
        <dependency org="org.apache.ivy" name="ivy" rev="2.4.0" conf="runtime->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

Here's the content the ivy-2.4.0.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:m="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/maven">
    <info organisation="org.apache.ivy"
        module="ivy"
        revision="2.4.0"
        status="release"
        publication="20141222174010"
    >
        <description homepage="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/" />
        <m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</m:properties__project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <m:properties__organization.logo>http://www.apache.org/images/asf_logo_wide.gif</m:properties__organization.logo>
        <m:properties__distMgmtSnapshotsName>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</m:properties__distMgmtSnapshotsName>
        <m:properties__distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</m:properties__distMgmtSnapshotsUrl>
        <m:maven.plugins>org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-remote-resources-plugin__null|org.apache.maven.plugins__maven-remote-resources-plugin__null</m:maven.plugins>
        <m:properties__sourceReleaseAssemblyDescriptor>source-release</m:properties__sourceReleaseAssemblyDescriptor>
    </info>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" description="runtime dependencies and master artifact can be used with this conf" extends="runtime,master"/>
        <conf name="master" visibility="public" description="contains only the artifact published by this module itself, with no transitive dependencies"/>
        <conf name="compile" visibility="public" description="this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths."/>
        <conf name="provided" visibility="public" description="this is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide it. It is only available on the compilation classpath, and is not transitive."/>
        <conf name="runtime" visibility="public" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath." extends="compile"/>
        <conf name="test" visibility="private" description="this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases." extends="runtime"/>
        <conf name="system" visibility="public" description="this scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."/>
        <conf name="sources" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the source artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="javadoc" visibility="public" description="this configuration contains the javadoc artifact of this module, if any."/>
        <conf name="optional" visibility="public" description="contains all optional dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="ivy" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="master"/>
        <artifact name="ivy" type="source" ext="jar" conf="sources" m:classifier="sources"/>
        <artifact name="ivy" type="javadoc" ext="jar" conf="javadoc" m:classifier="javadoc"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant" rev="1.7.1" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant-nodeps" rev="1.7.1" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant-trax" rev="1.7.1" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-httpclient" name="commons-httpclient" rev="3.0" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="oro" name="oro" rev="2.0.8" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-vfs" name="commons-vfs" rev="1.0" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="com.jcraft" name="jsch" rev="0.1.50" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="com.jcraft" name="jsch.agentproxy" rev="0.0.6" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="com.jcraft" name="jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory" rev="0.0.6" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="com.jcraft" name="jsch.agentproxy.jsch" rev="0.0.6" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.bouncycastle" name="bcpg-jdk14" rev="1.45" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.bouncycastle" name="bcprov-jdk14" rev="1.45" force="true" conf="optional->compile(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="3.8.2" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" rev="2.6" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.ant" name="ant-testutil" rev="1.7.0" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)">
            <exclude org="*" module="*" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="ant" name="ant-launcher" rev="1.6.2" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)">
            <exclude org="*" module="*" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="ant-contrib" name="ant-contrib" rev="1.0b3" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)">
            <exclude org="*" module="*" name="*" type="*" ext="*" conf="" matcher="exact"/>
        </dependency>
        <dependency org="xerces" name="xercesImpl" rev="2.6.2" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
        <dependency org="xerces" name="xmlParserAPIs" rev="2.6.2" force="true" conf="test->runtime(*),master(*)"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Comment: Could you please post your entire ivy.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an XML formatting problem.

The following examples demonstrate how ivy configurations can be used to manage separate "compile", "runtime" and "test" classpaths:

- [Ivy, what is the master configuration and why is it not pulling jvyaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417304/ivy-what-is-the-master-configuration-and-why-is-it-not-pulling-jvyaml/11420292#11420292)
- [Class not found with Ant, Ivy and JUnit - error in build.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979391/class-not-found-with-ant-ivy-and-junit-error-in-build-xml/15982144#15982144)