# Rename eclipse project from ant

Tags: eclipse, ant

I'm looking for an ant task that would allow me to do things like e.g. rename an Eclipse project, just as if I clicked "Refactor > Rename" (so it would rename both the directory, and the project name, and tell the workspace where to find the updated project).

I remember vaguely, that there was some project which already provides such tasks, but I can't find it anymore (or maybe I only dreamed it?)

If there isn't, then I'm ideally looking for a complete example how to implement something like this (including which libraries I need etc.)

Comment: The following answer has some ideas on how to use groovy to generate Elipse project and classpath files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794813/ant-script-to-choose-between-multiple-version-of-classpaths/10824812#10824812

Answer (score 0):

Two existing Ant addons with specific tasks for Eclipse i know of :

- [Ant4Eclipse](http://www.ant4eclipse.org/)
- [Ant-Eclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-eclipse/)

but i don't know if they provide a solution for your needs - never used them.
After all you may use some low level approach, means simply editing the eclipse config files
 (.project ..) programmatically !?