# how to add external jars/ant library to buildpath in eclipse using ant script

Tags: ant

I am searching from morning how to include external dependencies/jars in my project buildpath. I am building my project using ant and ivy. Ant is downloading the dependencies and creating a folder named lib in the project root folder. When I am trying to write code and use eclipse auto suggest to see the classes in the downloaded dependencies eclipse is not able to show them. Then I realized that the jars are in lib folder but not in classpath/buildpath. I am new to ant and I don't know an easy way to do this. I used this

```
<target name="resolve">
    <ivy:retrieve />
    <path id="gwtlibs">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
</target>
```

and even this

```
<target name="resolve">
    <ivy:retrieve />
    <path id="gwtlibs">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
</target>
```

But all my efforts failed. I could not see any thing like "Referenced libraries" in my project structure. Do I need to manually add the jars downloaded by going to buildpath and and add external jars option? I have experience with maven. When I do a maven build all external dependencies are downloaded and automatically added to project build path. But how I can achieve the same with ant?

Comment: Yes, you must add them manually to the eclipse build path.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the ivy [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task. Which is designed to create ANT paths using ivy configurations.

For an example of its use see:

- [How to avoid copying dependencies with Ivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609465/how-to-avoid-copying-dependencies-with-ivy/2611353#2611353)

For Eclipse integration I would suggest using the [ivyIDE](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/) plugin, which will ensure Eclipse uses ivy to cofiguration it's internal classpath.

Finally, the following answer has an example of how to generate the Eclipse ".classpath" directly from ANT.

- [Ant script to choose between multiple version of classpaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794813/ant-script-to-choose-between-multiple-version-of-classpaths/10824812#10824812)